# How to run multiple files and headers in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code, visual-c++

I'm trying to setup my visual studio code for c/c++ and it seems to work with 1 file but can't get it to work with multiple files. Any ideas?

I have a few files: main.cpp, Field.cpp, Field.h, Vector.cpp, Vector.h, Line.cpp, Line.h, Point.h, Ball.h. They're all linked together with includes and #pragma once correctly but don't seem to be running on vs code. Errors like these appear when I try to run main.cpp:

> C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
> C:\Users\ToXiC\AppData\Local\Temp\cccXESgP.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x151):
> undefined reference to `ballCase(Field&)' C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\ToXiC\AppData\Local\Temp\cccXESgP.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x2c8): undefined reference to` Field::hit(Point, double)'
> C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
> C:\Users\ToXiC\AppData\Local\Temp\cccXESgP.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x2fa):
> undefined reference to `operator<<(std::ostream&, Field const&)'

Any ideas?

Comment: With a build system. cmake, meson, etc.

Comment: Although switching to use CMake (and the CMake tools extension) for larger projects is a good option and will greatly help in the future the documentation tells you how to use more than 1 source file here: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_modifying-tasksjson](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_modifying-tasksjson)

Answer (score 0):

In visual studio, create an empty c++ project, then right click on project, navigate to Add->Existing item... and select all files together. You then need your entry point (main function) and that's it.